# Extensions of harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am interested in the following problem:

Let $\Omega, \Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be two Lipschitz domains such that $\Sigma \subset \Omega$ and $\Sigma$ is not dense in $\Omega$, and let $u \in H^1(\Sigma)$ be a function with the property that 
\begin{align*}
\Delta u=0 \qquad \text{ in } \Sigma.
\end{align*}

Does there exist a function $\tilde u \in H^1(\Omega)$ with the property that
\begin{align*}
\Delta \tilde u=0 \qquad \text{ in } \Omega
\end{align*}

and such that $\tilde u$ coincides with $u$ on $\Sigma$?

Can anyone kindly recommend a good reference for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stabbing at the dark: harmonic implies analytic, so take the power series of $u$ and consider it on the domain $\Omega$?

Comment: I did not see the $\mathbb R^3$. however already in the plane this is not true: take $\log |z|$: it cannot be extended at zero but it is harmonic on $\mathbb C^*$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $u=\log|z|$ and $\Sigma$ to be any domain that does not contain zero. Then $u$ is harmonic on $\Sigma$, but it cannot be extended to any domain $\Omega$ that contains $0$.

Edit: that was for $\mathbb R^2 \simeq \mathbb C$: I did not notice that OP asked about $\mathbb R^3$. As Daniel pointed out, a similar example can be taken in $\mathbb R^3$ by $u(x,y,z)=\|(x,y,z)\|_2^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the quick response. Are there conditions that one can impose on $u$ in order to ensure that the harmonic extension $\tilde u$ exists?

Comment: @Hassan not to my knowledge, but possibly. also, even if it's not what you are asking, you might be interested by this existence theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion!